# how to get src of image in javascript

Tags: javascript

I keep getting back "image undefined" from the `rpsFrontEnd()` funtion  from the
variable `humanImageChoice` although i have use  `this` to refer to the input by
the user. need your help pls.

```js
function rpsGame(yourChoice) {
  console.log(yourChoice);
  var humanChoice, botChoice;
  humanChoice = yourChoice.id;

  botChoice = numberToChoice(randToRpsInt(randToRpsInt));
  console.log('Computer Choice:' + botChoice);

  result = decideWinner(humanChoice, botChoice); //[0,1] human lost 
  console.log(result);

  message = finalMessage(result); //you won
  console.log(message);

  rpsFrontEnd(yourChoice, botChoice, message);
}

function rpsFrontEnd(humanImageChoice, botImageChoice, message) {
  var imageDatabase = {
    'rock': document.getElementById('rock').src,
    'paper': document.getElementById('paper').src,
    'scissors': document.getElementById('scissors').src
  }
  //removing the images onclicking an image
  document.getElementById('rock').remove();
  document.getElementById('paper').remove();
  document.getElementById('scissors').remove();

  //creatin divs for the image choices to be placed in

  var humanDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var botDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var messageDiv = document.createElement('div');

  humanDiv.innerHTML = "<img src='" + imageDatabase[humanImageChoice] + "'>"
  document.getElementById('flex-box-rps-div').appendChild(humanDiv);
}
```

```html
<div class="container-3">
  <h2>Challenge 3: Rock paper Scissors</h2>
  <div class="flex-box-rps" id="flex-box-rps-div">
    <img id="rock" src="static/imgs/rock.jpg" height="150px" width=" 150px" onclick="rpsGame(this)" />
    <img id="paper" src="static/imgs/paper.jpg" height="150px" width=" 
        150px" onclick="rpsGame(this)" />
    <img id="scissors" src="static/imgs/scissors.jpg" height="150px" width=" 
                  150px" onclick="rpsGame(this)" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Typo: The first argument to `rpsFrontEnd()` should be `humanChoice`, not `yourChoice`.

Comment: thanks much for the edit and the correction, it works now yeay

Answer (score 0):

Image src isn't getting correct. It will be,
in `rpsFrontEnd`function,

```
humanDiv.innerHTML = "<img src='" + imageDatabase[humanImageChoice.src] + "'>"
```

Or in `rpsGame` function,

```
 yourChoice.src
```

If this does not resolve the issue, please check your browser console. Maybe it getting another error for others function.